# In J2ME, do we need Verisign or other Digital Signature, to be able to read/write Memory phonecard?

Tags: java, java-me, permissions

I try to build and MMS application that read file from memory phonecard, and send it to other
After several try in the actual phone, I believe that we need Digital Signature to be able to read/write memory phonecard. I've check [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com) about its digital signature : is that a must for this kind of application?

Is there any free alternatif (that is, you don't need to buy a digital signature???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually send MMS and read files from the SD card, at least with most of the J2ME compatible devices (Nokia, Sony Ericssom, BlackBerry, LG...). The restrictions about what you can read/send vary from one platform to another.

If you don't sign your midlet, these operations will prompt  (with more or less frequency, again depending on the platform) to ask for permission. For example:

> Do you want to allow this midlet to read this file ...?

If you sign your midlet you can skip the runtime permission prompts, and the permission will only be asked during the installation.

Conclusion: You can do it for free, but your midlet will be a pain in the neck.

Comment: Ok, I should try it in at least two different application. I tried in NOkia (I forget the series), and it wont' display the image in memory card

Answer (score 2):

To perform IO without user permission (or atlease in *ask once* more ) you need your app to be running in trusted domain. doesn't matter using which certificate you sign your app. but it must be in trusted domain. I would strongly recommend to confirm from authority before you buy certificates

**Also See**

- [Understanding MIDP 2.0's Security Architecture](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/permissions/)

Comment: what you mean by trusted domain, isn't that why we need the verisign?

Comment: The link is dead. That article is now [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/index-156128.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cosign. It provides [digital signatures](http://www.arx.com) for all platforms. There's more info about their products on the Microsoft website.